# The various uses of 気 in isolation

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The expressions/phrases that involve 気 (ie: 気になる, 気にする, 気がついた, etc) are pretty well documented online. However, it seems difficult to find how to use 気 outside of these. For example, I recently encountered:

> 逃げる気ですね、優希ちゃん

(saying that Yuuki seems to be running away with the game)

> 何になる気だ

(asking "what will you become?" after another character says they will lose their human form)

In the first example, 気 to be functioning a bit like みたい or よう, while in the second, I'm not exactly sure what it is doing.

While I'd like an answer addressing what is being expressed in these examples, I would also like a more general coverage of how 気 is used outside of expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the examples that you gave:

> 逃げる気ですね、優希ちゃん

and

> 何になる気だ

気 here has a sense of *inclination* or *feeling*.  So, in the first example, it could be more literally translated as

> You're feeling like running away, right.

The last example you could translate as

> What do you want to become?

*want* is a bit strong.  気 has a much more vague meaning.  If you said something like

> する気になった

You might say that in English as "I got it into my head to do..."

Generally, 気 has a very broad range of meanings.

I find online dictionaries rather clunky at times.  If you know what you're looking for, they work.  But if you want to get a better feel for the nuance of things, they're just not very well organized for that purpose.

I would suggest digging out an old paper [和英辞典]{わえいじてん} and looking at the examples listed.  Even though my Obunsha dictionary is over 30 years old, it's still pretty good for perusing and getting a feel for the variety and shades of meanings for more idiomatic words, particularly words like 気.

Comment: Thank you! I really need to buy a paper dictionary it seems. So do you suggest the Obunsha one in particular?

Comment: @MegaZeroX I'm not recommending any particular brand.  Obunsha is what I have on my desk along with Kadokawa (but my Kadokawa is just a 国語辞典, meaning it's a dictionary for native speakers).  But, while I do like my Obunsha, I don't know whether there are better options out there now.  My Obunsha is written for native Japanese speakers learning English.  I've always been frustrated with dictionaries written for non-native speakers.